# Problema con variables y funciones

Tags: python, funciones, variables

estoy aprendiendo Python y tengo un problema, intento ejecutar este código:

```
def crearUsusario():
    nombre = input("Inserte un nombre de usuario: ")

crearUsusario()
print(nombre)
```

Pero me da error: NameError, alguna solucion? Gracias

Losiento todavia soy noob en python :(

Comment: Gracias por responder!!

Answer (score 2):

La variable `nombre` es local (interna) a la función `crearUsuario`. Es otras palabras, no es conocida fuera de la función.

Si quieres que se conozca fuera, debes retornarla:

```
def crearUsusario():
    nombre = input("Inserte un nombre de usuario: ")
    return nombre
```

y recuperarla donde llames a esa función:

```
nombre = crearUsusario)
print(nombre)
```

Aunque ambas variables de llaman igual, son distintas: una existe dentro de la función `crearUsuario` y la otra es global.

Comment: Anda, escribí exactamente lo mismo (y a la vez) en un comentario! Mejor lo borro XD

Comment: Gracias por responder!!